# XML performance app problem

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, nsxmlparser, libxml2

I am testing XML performance app. But instead of fetching iTunes xml I have created my a local xml file in the bundle. The content of the file is given below:

```
<Songs>
    <channel>
        <item>
            <title>
            title
            </title>
            <category>
            category
            </category>
            <itms:artist>
            artist
            </itms:artist>
            <itms:album>
            album
            </itms:album>
            <itms:releasedate>
            November 23, 1937
            </itms:releasedate>
        </item>
    </channel>
</Songs>
```

When I am parsing it with NSXMLParser release date is not showing, everything else is showing properly. But while I am parsing with Libxml2 parser app is crashing showing "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Unhandled error encountered during SAX parse.'" this on console.

Comment: can you try it with `November_23,_1937`

Comment: Can u try this 2002-09-24 option?

Comment: Thanks! For so quick response. But I tried both. No luck so far.[parseFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle]; its used, so according to this I fed the date.